# Red Hat Enterprise 5 display mode detection issue

Tags: redhat

I have installed Red Hat on my HP 550 laptop and the display resolution does not fit my Laptop's display.  My display works great with windows 7 and it is 1280 x 800 , once i enter in RedHat i see the screen like a box and does not fit the whole monitor of my laptop,  I log in with root password and try to change X display settings but there is just one setting -- 1024x700 -- and I can not change it.

What can be the problem that causes this?

Kind regards,
-- A.Xheladini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try a Linux forum for this question, but [here's a page that can help you](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/777575.html)